# Generar varios raster a partir de listas de archivos x,y,z en R

Tags: r, datagrid, netcdf4

Para otro proyecto he usado esta función para extraer valores de archivos en ascii, para lo que extraigo puntos específicos de una lista de coordenadas 'pts' (longitud, latitud):

```
files <-list.files(pattern='*.asc', recursive=TRUE, full.names=TRUE)  
pts= read.table("/home/pts.txt",sep="\t",head=F)
extractedData=list()         
   for(i in seq_along(files)) {
   extractedData[[i]] = extract(raster(files[i]), pts, method="simple")  
   }
```

La rutina anterior me funciona, y quisiera hacer algo similar pero generar raster o netcdf a partir de múltiples archivos que contienen x,y,z (sin nombre en las columnas).

Llevo varias horas tratando de generar raster sin éxito.
Tengo 1000 archivos en longitud, latitud, alturas (archivos .temp).

Consulta: ¿Cómo convertir a raster los 1000 archivos, crear lista y leer puntos con base en pts de forma similar al ejemplo anterior? DE lo que he leído ncdf4 o raster son los indicados, pero no he tenido éxito.

```
  #1. Lista a partir de 1000 archivos '.temp':
  tempf <-list.files(pattern='*.temp', recursive=F, full.names=TRUE)
```

Agradezco la guía.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la función lapply para generar cada raster en un elemento de la lista.

```r
library(raster)
tempf <- list.files(pattern='*.temp', recursive=F, full.names=TRUE)
lista_raster <- lapply(tempf, funcion(x){
  coordinates(x) <- ~ x + y # nombre de las columnas x e y
  gridded(x) <- TRUE
  result(raster(x))
}
lista_raster[[1]] # Primer raster
```

Comment: @Novvier.Gracias probaré-